# How to display IEnumerable<int> in JQGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities, jqgrid-asp.net

I'm trying to display IEnumerable int values in JQGrid.  As seen below column gmu is IEnumerable int but does not show correctly in the grid. Instead of the values, this is what shows in the grid for that gmu column:

System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[<>f__AnonymousType2`5[System.Int32,System.String,System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Int32],System.Int32]

```
var result = from x in test
                     group x by new { x.dau, x.population_estimate, x.year } into p
                     select new
                     {                             
                         dau = p.Key.dau,
                         population_estimate = p.Key.population_estimate,
                         year = p.Key.year,
                         gmu = p.Select(x => x.gmu)
                     };          


        int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
        int pageSize = rows;
        int totalRecords = results.Count();
        int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);


        var pageResults = result.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = (
                from pageResult in pageResults
                select new
                {
                    //id = pageResult.id,
                    cell = new[] { 
                                    pageResult.year.ToString(),
                                    pageResult.dau.ToString(), 
                                    pageResult.gmu.ToString(),                             
                                    pageResult.population_estimate.ToString(),                                       
                    }
                }).ToArray()
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add "ToArray()" after "Select" in your Linq statement.

```
gmu = String.Join<int>(", ", p.Select(x => x.gmu))
```

What's happening is that, when it goes to render your IEnumerable object, .NET is implicitly invoking the "ToString()" function (it's not smart enough to actually enumerate the object on its own initiative), resulting in what you see.

Comment: When I do that, my column now shows 'System.Int32[]'. However when I put a breakpoint and look at the code is shows the int[] array and the values correctly. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: My mistake.  You just want to show them comma-separated?  The above should work, converting the IEnumerable to a String.

Comment: Awsome!!  Thanks. Just a note for anyone using the above...make sure to add a comma between the ", " and p.Select...